# convert json to array and get array value

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here i tried to conver json into array and then fetching array value.
I checked SO threads and tried with similar approach, but still giving error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

<?php

$json = '[{"post_content": "nyone pls. guide me, for launching the website from where we can get the webspace and what should be the speed etc, the domain is booked through godaddy, Your technical guidance is appreciated. Thanks","name": "Uncategorized","taxonomy": "category"}, {"post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)

Basically both great design + web development","name": "services","taxonomy": "discussion_type"}, {"post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)

Basically both great design + web development","name": "Design","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)

Basically both great design + web development","name": "Front End","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Ajit Nazre (Harvard )Whole world is visiting what are you waiting for visit my website &amp; thanks for your visit !
get more updates on http://www.ajitnazre.com","name": "articles","taxonomy": "discussion_type"}, {"post_content": "Design Thinking for Startups.

Can a startup be designed specifically? Can you have a designer startup?
Maybe YES.

We are exploring the process of design thinking and how it applies to startups. Once complete, the process can be used to design a startup business, that will enable founders to take a correct roadmap, avoid traps and failures and post clear signs on strategy and direction.

Stay tuned.

#startupden","name": "Design Thinking","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Hello people! These are 5 questions, and will take less than a minute to fill up! This is really important for me. Thanks! 
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Axk7UZsZkiVXLroOk9Cc2wCgFZBTBWNOGgRU9nyYI1E/edit","name": "Survey","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Hello people! These are 5 questions, and will take less than a minute to fill up! This is really important for me. Thanks! 
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Axk7UZsZkiVXLroOk9Cc2wCgFZBTBWNOGgRU9nyYI1E/edit","name": "Food","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...","name": "Suggestion","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...","name": "Content","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...","name": "Tool","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Looking to buy short form video (30 seconds to 1 min ) across all genres . Should be original content only .","name": "buy-sell","taxonomy": "discussion_type"}, {"post_content": "Looking to buy short form video (30 seconds to 1 min ) across all genres . Should be original content only .","name": "Content","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach ($arr as $r)
    {
        echo $r['post_content'];
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is in different lines. It should be in one line. See below :-

```
<?php

    $json = '[{"post_content": "nyone pls. guide me, for launching the website from where we can get the webspace and what should be the speed etc, the domain is booked through godaddy, Your technical guidance is appreciated. Thanks","name": "Uncategorized","taxonomy": "category"}, {"post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)Basically both great design + web development","name": "services","taxonomy": "discussion_type"}, {"post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)Basically both great design + web development","name": "Design","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)Basically both great design + web development","name": "Front End","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Ajit Nazre (Harvard )Whole world is visiting what are you waiting for visit my website &amp; thanks for your visit !get more updates on http://www.ajitnazre.com","name": "articles","taxonomy": "discussion_type"}, {"post_content": "Design Thinking for Startups.Can a startup be designed specifically? Can you have a designer startup?Maybe YES.We are exploring the process of design thinking and how it applies to startups. Once complete, the process can be used to design a startup business, that will enable founders to take a correct roadmap, avoid traps and failures and post clear signs on strategy and direction.Stay tuned.#startupden","name": "Design Thinking","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Hello people! These are 5 questions, and will take less than a minute to fill up! This is really important for me. Thanks! https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Axk7UZsZkiVXLroOk9Cc2wCgFZBTBWNOGgRU9nyYI1E/edit","name": "Survey","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Hello people! These are 5 questions, and will take less than a minute to fill up! This is really important for me. Thanks! https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Axk7UZsZkiVXLroOk9Cc2wCgFZBTBWNOGgRU9nyYI1E/edit","name": "Food","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...","name": "Suggestion","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...","name": "Content","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...","name": "Tool","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}, {"post_content": "Looking to buy short form video (30 seconds to 1 min ) across all genres . Should be original content only .","name": "buy-sell","taxonomy": "discussion_type"}, {"post_content": "Looking to buy short form video (30 seconds to 1 min ) across all genres . Should be original content only .","name": "Content","taxonomy": "discussion_tag"}]';

    $arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    foreach ($arr as $r)
        {
            echo $r['post_content'];
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: @Khushbu: thanks, what you did? manually removed all new lines?

Answer (score 1):

Your input JSON is invalid, so when you decode it you will not get an array but `NULL`.
This is your issue.
Try to `var_dump($arr)` and you will get `NULL`
To fix this avoid changing lines and make your json in one line.

Answer (score 0):

This is working ,try this

```
$aa= '[
    {
        "post_content": "nyone pls. guide me, for launching the website from where we can get the webspace and what should be the speed etc, the domain is booked through godaddy, Your technical guidance is appreciated. Thanks",
        "name": "Uncategorized",
        "taxonomy": "category"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...Basically both great design + web development",
        "name": "services",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_type"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)Basically both great design + web development",
        "name": "Design",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Anyone know of a good Indian design firm for startups which also codes clean HTML and CSS (using technologies like sass, compass, grunt etc...)Basically both great design + web development",
        "name": "Front End",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Ajit Nazre (Harvard )Whole world is visiting what are you waiting for visit my website &amp; thanks for your visit !get more updates on http://www.ajitnazre.com",
        "name": "articles",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_type"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Design Thinking for Startups.Can a startup be designed specifically? Can you have a designer startup?Maybe YES.We are exploring the process of design thinking and how it applies to startups. Once complete, the process can be used to design a startup business, that will enable founders to take a correct roadmap, avoid traps and failures and post clear signs on strategy and direction.Stay tuned.#startupden",
        "name": "Design Thinking",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Hello people! These are 5 questions, and will take less than a minute to fill up! This is really important for me. Thanks! https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Axk7UZsZkiVXLroOk9Cc2wCgFZBTBWNOGgRU9nyYI1E/edit",
        "name": "Survey",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Hello people! These are 5 questions, and will take less than a minute to fill up! This is really important for me. Thanks! https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Axk7UZsZkiVXLroOk9Cc2wCgFZBTBWNOGgRU9nyYI1E/edit",
        "name": "Food",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...",
        "name": "Suggestion",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...",
        "name": "Content",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Please suggest best plagiarism tool other than smallseotool.com...",
        "name": "Tool",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Looking to buy short form video (30 seconds to 1 min ) across all genres . Should be original content only .",
        "name": "buy-sell",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_type"
    },
    {
        "post_content": "Looking to buy short form video (30 seconds to 1 min ) across all genres . Should be original content only .",
        "name": "Content",
        "taxonomy": "discussion_tag"
    }
]';
$arr = json_decode($aa, TRUE);
foreach ($arr as $r)
    {
        echo $r['post_content'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

new lines are not valid in json data. you should convert those to valid json.

try this

```
// convert new lines to corresponding json
$json = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('\r','\n'), $json);

$arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach ($arr as $r)
    {
        echo $r['post_content'];
    }
```